# objective-c - how to reverse a triangle cutout - OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, graphics, nsbezierpath

I need some help reversing a triangle cutout.

I can make the rectangle with a triangle cutout on it's right:

[image]

using these coordinates:

```
NSInteger imageWidth=12, imageHeight=22;
NSImage* destImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(imageWidth,imageHeight)];
[destImage lockFocus];

// Constructing the path
NSBezierPath *leftTriangle = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
[leftTriangle setLineWidth:1.0];
[leftTriangle moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(imageWidth+1, 0.0)];
[leftTriangle lineToPoint:NSMakePoint( 0, imageHeight/2.0)];
[leftTriangle lineToPoint:NSMakePoint( imageWidth+1, imageHeight)];
[leftTriangle closePath];
[[NSColor controlColor] setFill];
[[NSColor clearColor] setStroke];
```

...

What coordinates would I use to make the cutout on the other side, like this:

[image]

UPDATE: Inelegantly solved:

It helped to remember that measurements begin at the bottom left.

NSBezierPath *rightTriangle = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
[rightTriangle setLineWidth:1.0];
[rightTriangle moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(0.0, 29)];
[rightTriangle lineToPoint:NSMakePoint( imageWidth, 20)];
[rightTriangle lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(0.0, 11)];

Comment: I don't understand the dimensions in that code; it looks like the triangle is unrelated to the image it appears within.  How is the triangle rendered within the image?

Comment: To be honest, I copied that code. I guess I should figure out my own code

Comment: Well it looks like that code generates an image with just the triangle in, which must then be composited onto the main image somewhere else.  So the solution lies in the code you show (to reverse the direction of the triangle) and in that other code (to place it on the left side of the image).

Comment: Thank you for that info. I will try to remember where I got that snippet, and / or just rewrite. If I can find it quickly, I will add to my question. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I've added some more code, where this routine is called. I will go through it myself. Pressure day..

Comment: @trojanfoe, rereading your comments gave me the focus I needed, and I solved the issue today. If you write you comment as an answer, I can accept it. And thanks.

Comment: Don't worry it's not important;  If I was solving this issue I would have the triangle images pre-made, included as part of the app resources, and would then composite them at runtime with the target image.  Code to do compositing is pretty commonly available from this, and other, sites.

Comment: Yea, I may change to compositing images. I have an animation working between frames. I'll see how it looks, and thanks again.